# wordpress wp e commerce product data get in another data base?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible for wordpress content get in current database.But wordpress e-commerce product page get the products in another data base.

Answer (score 0):

Check out HyperDB:

http://codex.wordpress.org/HyperDB

> HyperDB is a replacement for the standard wpdb class which adds the
>   ability to use multiple databases. **HyperDB supports partition of
>   data** as well as replication.